# How to count the number of edges in a CFG in LLVM

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I am just learning how to implement a pass in LLVM. I have generated the CFG for the code and now I want to count the number of edges in the CFG in each function.

I was hoping there would be an API that I can I can use to count the number of edges in the CFG or do I have to do some sort of a tree traversal.

Thank you.

Comment: `llvm::TerminatorInst::getNumSuccessors()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no API that gives you that directly, IMHO. But it's easy to implement.

[This sample](https://github.com/eliben/llvm-clang-samples/blob/master/src_llvm/bb_toposort_sccs.cpp) is a LLVM pass that sorts the basic blocks of a function in topological order. It demonstrates how to run over BBs in a function and look at BB successors, so it has all the building blocks to implement what you need, and more.

Comment: Thank you. Also, is it possible to write two passes in the same cpp file? I was thinking, both passes can be Registered. Any insight on this is appreciated.

Comment: @user2058668: yes, it's possible to write multiple passes in a single C++ file

Comment: I managed to get the number of edges in the CFG. But I am wondering how to calculate the number of loops in the CFG.